# Overwriting text file in C++

Tags: c++, file

I have created a banking program in `C++` and every time a user creates account their details are to be stored into a text file. I have created the code that does this, but when I create the first account it will store the information, and when I create the second it overwrites it, which is not what I want to to do yet.

Here is the code I am using:

```
ofstream myfile; 
myfile.open("test.txt"); //open myfile.txt
myfile << setw(10) << "=Account Number=" << setw(20) << "=Customer Name=" << setw(20) << "=Balance=" << endl;
myfile << "=========================================================================================";
myfile << setw(10) << Account_no << setw(20) << name << setw(20) << address << setw(20) << intialAmount; //send values
myfile.close();//close file
```

How can I get it to move to a new line after the first customer has been created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructor of ofstream takes a mode option ([see here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/ofstream/)).
So open it like :

```
ofstream myfile("test.txt",std::ofstream::app);
```

Comment: Yeah, no probs. Another Question how could i overwrite the details if i need to. So for example A customer wants to change their address how could i get that to update in the text file?

Comment: This will be difficult for a plain text file. Maybe you want a more complex type of file (like XML or JSON), but you should open a new thread for that.

Answer (score 0):

To build upon Kiroxas's code, this one first checks if there's already a customer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream fil("test.txt");

    string f((istreambuf_iterator<char>(fil)), istreambuf_iterator<char>()); 
    //read into string

    fil.close();

    if (f.length() < 1) // if no previous customer in file
    {

    ofstream myfile;

    myfile.open("test.txt");

    myfile << setw(10) << "=Account Number=" << setw(20) << "=Customer Name=" 
    << setw(20) << "=Balance=" << endl; 

    myfile << "============================================" 
           << "============================================="; 

    myfile << setw(10) << Account_no << setw(20) 
           << name << setw(20) << address 
           << setw(20) << intialAmount; //send values to start of file

    myfile.close(); //close file

    }

    else //if file contains previous customer
    {
        ofstream myfile;

        myfile.open("test.txt", ios::app); 
        //ios::app tells it to write to the end of the file

        myfile << setw(10) << "=Account Number=" << setw(20) 
               << "=Customer Name=" 
               << setw(20) << "=Balance=" 
               << endl;
               
        myfile << setw(10) << Account_no << setw(20) 
               << name << setw(20) << address 
               << setw(20) << intialAmount; //send values 
    }
}
```

**NOTE:**

## One

`ios::app` has the same function as `std::ofstream::app`, it's just shorter!

## Two

Do not expect it to compile because I have not declared your account info variables (`Account_no` and et cetera). Until you declare them, it won't compile...